# I need to integrate Skype For Business SDK's in a React Native app

Tags: react, skype

After Googling a while, I couldn't find any plugin or implementation on how to integrate Skype For Business into a React Native app. I know I can create my own bridge, but I hope to find an out-of-the-box solution.

Thanks in advance!